# How to find out if a property is defined in placeholder in Spring?

Tags: spring, properties, undefined, placeholder

Due to some backward compatible reasons, some old apps didn't define a new property in its app.properties, which is referred in a shared Spring context.xml thru placeholders.  Is there a way in Spring to find out if a property is defined in the placeholder?

There are posts about setting null default values using Spring expression language.  But, I don't see an answer on how to determine if a property is defined in the placeholder, or you'd get "Could not resolve placeholder ...".

I'm looking for something like

`<constructor-arg value="#{someAPI('my.new.prop') ? ${my.new.prop} : #null}" />`

Your input is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just set default value for placeholder. In case property is not found, default is used. For example `${my.new.prop:'default.value'}`. Notice the colon.

Comment: @Vaelyr, That's the first thing I tried. But, somehow it always returns the default value, regardless if I define that property or not.  Any ideas?  I'm using spring-context-3.2.xsd.

Comment: I know what's going on!!!  I had a 2nd placeholder with higher priority, values were used to override the default values (systemPropertiesModeName="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE") at runtime.  But, even when the 2nd properties file doesn't exist, Spring treats it as if the 2nd file was there, which overrides the property defined in the 1st file.  I think that's a Spring bug.

Comment: The override has nothing to do with it I believe, it just lets system properties take precedence if they are passed in (manually usually). Are you sure your files are properly loaded from the classpath first of all, and that the properties are actually injected into your Spring app.

Comment: Yes.  With the 2nd placeholder in place, I wouldn't get my.new.prop, regardless if I defined it, I always get the default.value.  If I comment out the 2nd one, it get the correct value.

Comment: To make it clearer, I have many other properties that work perfectly as expected, with and without the 2nd override placeholder.  The only thing not working is the conditional one we discussed here.  I may write a complete answer later when I have some time, to prove it's a Spring bug.